# How to show local language fonts in Chrome?

Tags: languages, chrome-for-android, fonts

How to show Gujarati language font in Chrome for Android? I cannot read any Gujarati site like `divyabhaskar.com`, etc.

By the way in Opera Mini for Android browser there is the ability to show bitmap fonts for complex scripts. After enabling this option in Opera Mini I can read Gujarati fonts very easily. I tested all browsers available for Android but only Opera Mini seems to work. I regularly use Chrome so I want this function in Chrome so I can read my local language news sites online.

Comment: Why no body answer?